# Bypass google ads from referring page

Tags: java, php, html

I want to block direct access of a page below code works fine even if I refresh the page but when I use ads on this page, I got ads crawling issue. Google bot or other ad bot crawl the page directly which leads the bot to 404 page.

```
<?php
session_start();// At the very top of your page. Literally THE TOP.
// Set our session variable only if it is not currently set. 
if (!isset($_SESSION['referrer'])) {
$_SESSION['referrer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header('location:404.php');
exit;} ?>
```

It also show google bot a 404 page on crawling.

Any idea how to handle this?

How we can do this with php or java or htaccess direct access block for a page but excluding google bot.

Comment: You can start looking into using a robots.txt file for crawlers restrictions.

Comment: could you please give me the idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so one way to restricts bots access, or basically ask them not to index a particular page is using robots.txt file.

This file has to be accessible at the **root** of your domain e.g: `example.com/robots.txt` and contains something like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Allow: /admin/admin.php

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

As you can see this gives you the ability to allow/disallow robots access to certain pages / directories (paths) to your website.

It also empowers you to allow/disallow based on the user-agent (e.g: bot) for example:

```
User-agent: Bingbot
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Keep in mind that robots can ignore your robots.txt file, especially abusive bots like those run by hackers looking for security vulnerabilities, so you might want to restrict any sensitive information rendered on the page in the first place.

For a list of some known bots/crawlers [see this link](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/web-crawlers) - it also has probably more detailed explanation about robots.txt